# In C#/VS 2010, how can I suppress error messages for files not marked to compile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, error-list

Ok, we have a 'pseudo-c#' file that we've added to the solution for reference.  While it does have a `.cs` extension (to let VS take a stab at color-coding it since it's pretty big and that helps with readability) the file itself isn't marked to be compiled with the action set to 'none'.

Now, when we do a full build, everything builds just fine and the file is ignored as it's supposed to be.  However, the error window is showing all the errors from the faux code.  We of course can change the extension which gets rid of the errors, but then we lose syntax coloring.

Now I'd assume since we explicitly marked that file as 'do not compile' and since the errors are actually ignored by the compiler, they wouldn't show up, but obviously that isn't the case.

So anyone have any idea on how to hide errors that are generated in files that are marked to be excluded from the compiler?

---

Update:

Because people keep suggesting work-arounds, I want to be clear that we're already using work-arounds. That's not what I'm after here.  I'm trying to find out specifically if there is some setting or feature in VS that we can enable/disable that says 'Hey, you're not being compiled so you don't get to be in the error list!'  Not sure there even is such a thing, but if so, that's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Exclude the file from your project. Right click the file in question, and choose "Exclude". To view this file, select "Show all files" at the top of your Solution Explorer, and you can edit your code with full syntax highlighting.
2. Use a preprocessor `#ifdef` to conditionally include and exclude blocks (or files) of code. Note that non-included blocks of code will not be highlighted (and checked for errors).

Comment: Yes, I know about both of those things, but both of them defeat what we're trying to do... have a reference file *in* the project that has syntax highlighting.  And as soon as you open the file (from #1) it's added to the error list again.

Comment: But if it's closed, we can't use it as a reference.  Makes coding really frustrating having to constantly open and close the file. That's just dealing with one frustration over another.  Perhaps what I'm asking simply can't be done (e.g. if syntax highlighting is active, it will show errors.)

Comment: @MarquelV: Have you considered opening the file in a separate VS instance? (That doesn't have your project open)

Comment: Yes, just as I could also open it in a third-party text editor that does syntax-highlighting.  But again, I'm specifically asking if there's a way to suppress the errors from appearing in the VS error list, again because IMO, if the file isn't marked to be compiled, they should not appear there.  I may report this as a bug to MSFT.

Comment: There is no way to suppress errors like that at the moment. Only warnings.

Comment: Even though it looks like my question doesn't have an answer, I'll still mark this because it does show people the work-arounds we've been using.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to exclude the file from the project and ensure 'show all files' is on in visual studio. That way you will be able to see the file and still get syntax highlighting when you open it.

Comment: Yes, but as I said above, as soon as you open the file it's added to the error list again so this doesn't really work.

Comment: Another thing I found... you don't actually have to exclude it, just close it, and the errors go away.  Odd.  I'm really starting to think the error-checking is linked with the syntax highlighting, which would kind of make sense.